# JSTL radio button being displayed regardless of the when conditions

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am making an application where there is a radio button. The goal is to remember what the user inputted and keep track of it for when it goes back to that same page. However, regardless of if my when statement is true or false the button is still being displayed. Here is the code.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${grace == 'off'}">
           <input type="radio" id="grace" name="grace"/>
    </c:when>
     <c:when test="${grace == 'on'}">
         <input type="radio" id="grace" name="grace" checked="checked"/>
     </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Even though the grace attribute is being set to off in my java application, both radio buttons are still being output. What is wrong with my code ? How do I change it so that when the attribute grace equals off the button will be unchecked and when on it will be checked. Thank you !

P.S in case this is the source of the error.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"  version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="false"/>
    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        omit-xml-declaration="true" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have two radio buttons, first off. `checked` should be set dependent on a boolean, and then you have a single line of code intead of 8 lines. As for why this doesn't work, you haven't supplied any of the code where `grace` is set, or checked what its actual value is. `<c:out value="${grace}"/>` or `<c:out value="${grace == 'off'}"/>` can be used to debug.

Comment: I have debugged my grace value, and it is properly being set to on and off in the right circumstances. How would I go about making checked set dependent on a boolean ? When I set checked to false, the button is still being checked.

Comment: You can use a ternary statement, like this:
`checked="${grace eq 'on' ? 'checked' : ''}"`. If you're unfamiliar, it's basically `test ? (return this if test true) : (return this if test false)`

Comment: Thank you. What value should checked be assigned to make it not checked, because no matter what i set it to, null, false, empty, or just including checked, causes the button to be checked.

Comment: Ah, right. This is a bit of an anomaly in HTML and a poor design choice, where the value of `checked` doesn't matter. The only thing that matters if `checked` exists. So this should work `${grace eq 'on' ? 'checked' : ''}` and you can omit `checked=`